Why am I getting a frame-ancestor error when trying to use Amazon Connect Streams
The Error:
The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource (frame-ancestors) at because it violates the following directive: “frame-ancestors 'self'”
Background:
When I attempt to load the page using this script:
var containerDiv = document.getElementById("container-div"); 
var instanceURL = "[Their Instance].my.connect.aws/ccp-v2"; 
// initialize the streams api 
function init() 
{ // initialize the ccp 
    connect.core.initCCP(containerDiv, { 
        ccpUrl: instanceURL,
        loginUrl: '[Their Instance Login URL]', 
        softphone: 
        {
            allowFramedSoftphone: true, 
        } 
    }); 
}

The iframe is prevented from loading and provides the initial error I provided. Is there something I need to instruct them to do on their end to allow embedding beyond our site being an accepted origin? Does the AWS accepted origins allow local host (for testing) also? I am doing this in dev locally on my machine.
I am attempting to use the amazon connect streams JS to embed a third party client's amazon connect into our site (they are working with us to do this, and have added our site to their accepted origins).
I also went through IIS (which we use to host our app) and modified the HTTP headers we are using to allow embed on our end.
Info:
Our application uses C# and ASP.NET, the page this is being embedded into is a standard aspx page.
They have provided the instance and I am able to directly work with the third party client.

If you haven't added your domain as an "Approved Origin" in the Amazon Console yet, please be sure to do so.

Yes @EJoshuaS "I am attempting to use the amazon connect streams JS to embed a third party client's amazon connect into our site (they are working with us to do this, and have added our site to their accepted origins)"

@user26384446 For clarification, I wasn't the original answererer, I just edited it.

Ah!  @squifpahotmailcom  Sorry: See above comment
